# python 3 Iterating lists of lists parallel to eachother

Tags: python

I am making a calculator that calculates *x* amount of *y* materials for *z* endproduct. Since I will need lists to work as parameters, right now I need 2 lists, 1 for *x* and 1 for *y*. However, I am convinced that I can do all this with 1 nested list per *z*. How though?

Current code:

```
def calc(endproduct,formulalist,materiallist):
   amount = int(input())
   print('to make ' + str(endproduct) + ', you will need:')
   for entry,entry2 in zip(materiallist,formulalist):
      print(entry   +': ' + str(int(entry2) * amount))
      print('')
   print('success!')


electromagnet_formula = [4,3]
electromagnet_material = ['copper','tin']

calc('electromagnet',electromagnet_formula,electromagnet_material)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to define a list of pairs?  You can do something like this: `electromagnet_requirements: [('copper', 4), ('tin', 3)]`

Comment: @augurar if I do it like that, can I still have an arbitrary amount of sublists?

Comment: also, if I group them that, can I still carry out the input*formula math?

Comment: Yes, you can put as many elements in each tuple as you want.  The example I gave is exactly what `zip(materiallist,formulalist)` returns (assuming you are using Python 2), so you can use it the same way.

Comment: I'm using python 3 tho

Comment: In that case `zip()` returns an iterator, but if you do `list(zip(materiallist, formulalist))` you will see the same thing.  You should look up a Python tutorial because I can't teach you all of Python in the comment section!  :)